# PDO Insert unknown sql errors

Tags: sql, pdo

I am trying to insert into my database, and the only problem I can find is the sql not being correct somehow. I tried searching up the errors, but they are confusing at to what they are.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbvideos;", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Video ('Channel ID', 'Name', 'VideoDescription', 'VideoLocation') VALUES (:chanID, :vidName, :vDesc, :vLoc)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(":chanID"=>$_POST['selectedChannel'], ":vidName"=>$_POST['videoName'], ":vDesc"=>$_POST['viddesc'], ":vLoc"=> $VideoLocation));
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
```

With error output:

```
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID, Name, VideoDescription,VideoLocation) VALUES ('1', 'Testing Video', 'This is' at line 1 )
```

I pre-checked the variables (types match database, and they exist and with validation on previous page). The connection works fine. So SQL is the only error I can find.

Comment: Enclose names in back ticks (`) not quotes (') ? Also, it it not a good idea to have spaces in column names. Use an underscore instead?

Answer (score 1):

I understand having no space in names- that one slipped my mind (I am usually on top of that, even when saving files). Some how removing the space and removing ' quotes made it work. (I originally used ' quoted because I saw some people use it so I though it would fix the problem).

Thank You Ryan Vincent.